# Count different data from one SQL query

Tags: mysql, count

I want to get the same results in SQL 2 as in SQL 1 but somehow that SQL query only count the total amount of data for every date, based on the `WHERE`.

**SQL 1** (displays the right amount of data for each day)

```
SELECT DATE(datetime_logged) AS date,
COUNT(data_status) AS status_a

FROM activity
WHERE id_user = '1'
AND DATE(datetime_logged) != CURDATE()
AND data_status = 'online'
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_logged)
ORDER BY DATE(datetime_logged) DESC
LIMIT 40
```

[image: result-1]

**SQL 2** (displays the wrong amount of data for each day)

```
SELECT DATE(datetime_logged) AS date,
(SELECT COUNT(data_status) 
         FROM activity 
         WHERE id_user = '1' 
         AND DATE(datetime_logged) != CURDATE() 
         AND data_status = 'online') AS status_a

FROM activity
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_logged)
ORDER BY DATE(datetime_logged) DESC
LIMIT 40
```

[image: result-2]

**The table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_channel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_game` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_suppressed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `data_game` text,
  `datetime_logged` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_datelog` (`datetime_logged`)
)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you just need to tie the correlated subquery to the main query with:

```
AND a.datetime_logged=sub.datetime_logged
```

Example:

```
SELECT DATE(a.datetime_logged) AS date,
(SELECT COUNT(sub.data_status) 
         FROM activity sub
         WHERE sub.id_user = '1' 
         AND DATE(sub.datetime_logged) != CURDATE() 
         AND sub.data_status = 'online'
         AND a.datetime_logged=sub.datetime_logged) AS status_a

FROM activity a
GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime_logged)
ORDER BY DATE(a.datetime_logged) DESC
LIMIT 40
```

Comment: Your solution worked as I wanted but the SQL query slows down the website **extremely** much! From 0-1.5 seconds to easily over 10 seconds.

Comment: Probably an indexing issue on the date field.  I'm not much help on mySQL unfortunately.  Your first query was the better approach in my opinion anyway!  Why not just use that?

Comment: Ok. I did use my approach except I added `AND DATE(a.datetime_logged) = DATE(sub.datetime_logged)` and fixed so I could use that functionality.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!  The first query you wrote is definitely the faster approach as it doesn't have to compare the activity table to itself for a count.

Comment: Yes, but the new SQL query (the one you provided) slows down the website very much. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Probably an indexing issue, I can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: I tried to added an index to `data_status`  but that didn't make it better :/